# How to fetch all the records between date in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I am fetching this error:

DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (11-08-33) at position 7 (3): Unexpected character"

```
 $fromDate = Carbon::parse($request->input('start'))->format('Y-m-d');
$toDate = Carbon::parse($request->input('end'))->format('Y-m-d');
$date_range = [$fromDate . ' 00:00:00', $toDate . ' 23:59:59'];

$data = DB::where('projects')
->whereBetween('created_at', $date_range)
->get();
```

Comment: You are missing table(), DB::table('projects')

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify `Carbon` unput string format, So, In this case you can change your code like below :

```
$input_date_format="d-m-y";//your date input format

$fromDate = Carbon::createFromFormat($input_date_format,$request->input('start'))->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00');
$toDate = Carbon::createFromFormat($input_date_format,$request->input('end'))->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59');


//instead of `DB::where`, use `DB::table`
$data = DB::table('projects')->whereBetween('created_at',[$fromDate, $toDate ])->get();
```

Note: you can also use `str_replace` in order to replace `-` with `/` and your code will work!

Comment: Thanks Soheli Rahmat. But now I am receiving "Trailing data" error.

Comment: Test With `\Datetime::createFromFormat($your_format,$input_data)->format($your_requested_format)`!